# Create a linked list using base a class and a derived class

Tags: c++

How can I create a linked list using a base class and a derived class

Eg.:

```
class Base { 
    int id;
    Base *next;
};
class Derived : public Base {
    string name;
};  

Base *list = NULL;

Base *b = new Base();
b->next = list;
list = b;

Derived *d = new Derived();
d->next = list;
list = d;

Base *itr = list;
while(itr) {
    if(typeid(Base) == typeid(*itr)) {
        cout << "Base: " << itr->id << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Derived: " << itr->id << " and " << itr->name << endl;
    }
    itr = itr->next;
}
```

My approach does not work! Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you need this? is inheritance the only solution?

Comment: I want to build a graph. But, I want two types of Vertices: Super Vertex and Vertex. A Super Vertex has all the features of a Vertex, adding a list of Vertices from which they originated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do works fine. See this complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Base {
    Base *next; int id;
    Base(int id) : id(id) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int id2;
    Derived(int id, int id2) : Base(id), id2(id2) {}
};

void link(Base *n, Base **list) {
    n->next = *list; *list = n;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Base *list = 0;
    link(new Base(10), &list);
    link(new Derived(20, 21), &list);
    link(new Base(30), &list);
    link(new Derived(40, 41), &list);

    for (Base *p = list; p; p=p->next) {
        if (typeid(*p) == typeid(Base))
            printf("Base(%i)\n", p->id);
        else
            printf("Derived(%i, %i)\n", p->id, ((Derived *)p)->id2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However you must have at least one virtual member for `typeid` to work.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. I did not know needed have at least one virtual member for typeid to work! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Couple problems:

- Fields are private
- You have to cast to Derived in your else to be able to use name();

Probably a better solution than checking the typeid's would be to define a virtual function that returns a string representation and override it in Derived.

Comment: Could use a virtual function, this is a great idea. But I not like this solution. I want to build a graph. But, I want two types of vertices: Super Vertex and Vertex. A Super Vertex has all the features of a Vertex, adding a list of vertices from which they originated.

Comment: There are still two types of vertices. Make the vertex type responsible for this extra behavior. Usually RTTI indicates a shaky design. See http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Run-Time_Type_Information__RTTI_ for a more comprehensive argument

Comment: Thanks, I liked the article, will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inheritance this situation does not call for it. You **need to know** the difference between a Vertex and a Super Vertex. If inheritance was the right thing to do you would not need to know the difference. Try the following approach.

```
class SuperNode;
class Base {
public:
    int id;
    Base *next;
    SuperNode* next;
};

class SuperNode {
public:
    string name;
    int id;
    Base *next;
    SuperNode* next;
};
```

Comment: Great idea. I also thought in that solution. However, I have to replicate methods? Eg, I need to create a method to add an vertex and another method to add an super-vertex?